# Add different id to div using the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know how i can add different id using the same class what im trying to do is to edit each individual draggable what i need is to generate a different id so i can edit each draggable my id="monkey" what i need is id="monkey1" monkey2 exc

```js
var z = 1; //value to make div overlappable

$('#addText').click(function (e) {
    /** Make div draggable **/
    $('<div />', {
        class: 'ui-widget-content',
        appendTo: '.container',
        draggable: {
            containment: 'parent',
            start: function( event, ui ) {
                $(this).css('z-index', ++z);
            }
        }
    });
});


$(document).on("dblclick", '.text', function()
{
    $(this).hide();    $(this).closest('.item').find('.edit_text').val($(this).text()).show();
});

$(document).on("click", ".edit_text", function()
{
    return false;
});


$(document).on("click", function()
{
    var editingText = $('.edit_text:visible');
    if (editingText.length)
    {
        editingText.hide();
        editingText.closest('.item').find('.text').text($(editingText).val()).show();
    }
});

ko.bindingHandlers.draggable={
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $(element).draggable();
    }
};

var vm=function(){
    var self=this;
    self.items=ko.observableArray();
    self.textContent = ko.observable('');
    self.init=function(){
        self.items([]);
    }
    self.remove=function(item){
        console.log(item);
        self.items.remove(item);
    }
    self.addNew = function() {
      self.items.push( self.textContent() );
      self.textContent('');
    }
    self.init();
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```css
<style>.item{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background:yellow;
    z-index: 1;
    display:block;
}

.edit_text
{
    display: none;
}

.fix_backround
{
    background-color: transparent;
}

.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 2px solid;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
</style>
```

```html
<textarea data-bind="value: textContent" Placeholder="Type text to append"></textarea>
<button data-bind="click: addNew">Generate New Div</button>

<div class="container">
<div data-bind="foreach:items" class="fix_backround">
    <div id="monkey" href="#" class="item" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">
        <span data-bind="click:$parent.remove">[x]</span><br/><br/>
        <center><span class="text" data-bind="text:$data"></span></div><input class="edit_text"/></center>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

Comment: Increment an index each time you add an item and append it to the newly generated div?

Comment: How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fiddle demonstrating how you could do this:

https://jsfiddle.net/xtrinch/etjj8xnz/

The main part of it is:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.draggable={
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $(element).draggable();
        $(element).attr('id', 'monkey'+itemsAdded)

        itemsAdded = itemsAdded + 1
    }
};
```

Comment: Hope you can see the fiddle now, I forgot to make it public :)